# Do you HAVE TO write different layout for different devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I just want some seasoned and experienced educated answer on this, a quick answer will be enough:

I want to use as much `constraint layout` and percentage parameters as possible for the sake that my app will adjust flawlessly and seamlessly to all screen resolutions above the certain resolution, `1080p` for example... like web pages on different browser screens.

So I invested a great deal of time in it and now it seems the more I explore into this realm the more I came to realize my initial purpose may be fundamentally flawed - it seems that a more common practice is that you must first `DETECT` the resolution of the device your app has been being run on, then load different layout correspondingly.

But I'm not giving up, can you help me decide which direction I should take?

Comment: This is impossible to answer in the abstract. It depends entirely upon your UI design. In general, we may *try* to use a single layout where that seems likely to work, and we fall back to having 2+ versions of the layout for different screen sizes where it proves to be necessary.

Comment: Not necessarily. But it's highly adviced.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your query is that what is the best practice to develop an app that "adjust's flawlessly and seamlessly to all screen resolutions".
I have dealt with several platform level concerns/bugs working for core android firm, and most of the issue applications reported were caused by incorrect usage of these norms.
For example:
- Not providing bitmap resources tailored to each of the generalized density buckets

Developers link might be of some use if you can spend some time going through the basic:
 [developers_multiscreen](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Do you HAVE TO write different layout for different devices?

No.

If you want highly different layouts for different devices.

E.g. if in tablet version you'd have to add views that you won't use in phone version, then you can:

1) handle their visibility and use just one layout, but...

2) if these views are too many, or they are particular views that require a lot of RAM (like a map view) you can decide to split the layout in two parts for better performance on phones.

Anyway, in code, you'll have to check programmatically the layout that the system is going to use, and you have to be very accurate in order to avoid incongruence and then glitches or crashes.
So you could decide to sacrifice performance for stability in most cases, and very rarely use different layouts.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, on a related note: will relativeLayout better than ConstraintLayout if I want to "layout once, run everywhere"?

Comment: ConstraintLayout has a lot of advantages which could be very useful, but personally I've ever found a good way to make everything using just LinearLayout, FrameLayout, Spaces and custom views (I prefer XML writing instead of the graphical layout).
So you can achieve almost everything with both, but RelativeLayout offers less options

Answer (score 0):

You have to make following Screen Sizes layout files

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

you have to set the sizes for the smallest screen width.

refer:https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you I think I know what you are suggesting, I think I cheated around that problem by using PNG everywhere ;)